# Excel VBA Function error on Call within a Sub

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to use this function to test whether a cell is bolded:

```
Public Function IsBold(c As Range) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Handler
    IsBold = c.Font.bold
    Exit Function

    Handler:
        If Err.Number = 94 Then IsBold = True
End Function
```

Then I created a macro that does formatting and also checks a range of cells using the IsBold function above.  When the macro runs the IsBold function throws '#Name' in the cells using it and the macro enters debug mode.

How do I get this to be usable in my macro so that conditional formatting that references the IsBold function works properly?

Comment: Where is the macro stored? It should be in a standard code module. My guess is that you have it in a sheet module. If that isn't the problem -- show the code which is causing the error. The above code is fine, so the answer to your question involves information which you haven't provided.

Comment: Yes, it is during the macro run.  The Sub of the macro uses the IsBold, but I get a run time 1004 mid-way through the macro.  When I debug the line is: 'ExecuteExcel4Macro"(2,1,""General"")".  The cell that ref's the 'IsBold' has #Name, so the conditional formatting of the macro that uses that output, which is now #Name won't execute properly.  

My issue seems to be getting the cell that ref's the 'IsBold' to display correctly a 'Y' or 'N', which it does under non-macro ran circumstances.

Comment: It would help if you edit the question to include the code which is actually throwing the error.

Comment: Also -- `ExecuteExcel4Macro` should be used sparingly. That seems like it might be the problem. It is rare that there is a good use case for this rather than a pure VBA solution.

Comment: So here we have with that line commented out

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(IsBold(RC[-28]),""Y"",""N"")"
    Range("AC8").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=""IF(AC8=Y,TRUE,FALSE)"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    'ExecuteExcel4Macro "(2,1,""General"")"
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0

Comment: Something like that belongs in the question itself, not the comments. In any event -- *where* is the code for `IsBold`? If it is in a sheet code module, you get that `#NAME?` in the cell. If it is in a standard code module, you shouldn't.

Comment: The IsBold function is in my module directly above the Sub code that is written above.

Comment: But -- what *type* of module is it? Does it say something like "Sheet 1"? Or is this a module which you explicitly inserted?

Comment: It is labeled as Module3 and it was created through a recorded macro.  It is located in my VBAProject Personal and in my Modules folder.

Comment: If it is in your `Personal` macro book, then you would need to use `=PERSONAL.XLS!IsBold` in the cell. Try it with that.